# [Android][Emulator] Create custom system image from emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have an Android emulator where I write a system app for. Example I am working on my_system_app.apk and it is loaded as a system app in the emulator.

I would like to create system-image based on the emulator, and create new emualators from that image. Goal: Create an emulator from android-33-custom, where once the emualtor is created it has  my_system_app.apk in system apps

How can that be done?

Comment: There is a nice bit little bit old blog post about how to change emulator system image - I would give it a try: https://www.vishalon.net/blog/tutorial-how-to-make-a-change-permanent-in-system-folder-for-android-emulator-yaffs2ext4 Just make sure you are not trying to modify an image tagged as "Google API" as those images are encrypted to prevent modification.